# finding substrings within arrays - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring

I need to find the substrings within arrays.
If I have an array: `["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "xyz"]`, the method should return me the array members: `"abc", "abcd", "abcde"` as each is a substring or a superstring of the other, but it should exclude "xyz".
What is the best possible method in javascript.

Comment: what will be the result of this: ['ab','abc','bc','abbc','bb','abb','ac','ababc','abbbc','bbc'] - the desierd logic is not well defined

Comment: ['ab','abc','bc','abb','ababc','abbbc','bbc'], as here you wont find any totally different string array elements

Comment: why not bb? it's substring of other

Comment: ya it can also, missed to add it

Comment: why not `abbc`? `ab` and `bc` are substrings of `abbc` right?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var arr = ["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "xyz"];

console.log(arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.indexOf('abc') > -1;
}));
```

**Edit:** Use `Array#some` if you want to make filter based of *some* values in the array with respect to current element!

```js
var arr = ["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "xyz"];

console.log(arr.filter(function(el, index) {
  return arr.some(function(e, i) {
    if (i !== index) {
      return e.indexOf(el) > -1 || el.indexOf(e) > -1;
    }
    return false;
  })
}));
```

Comment: This is not expected, I need to dynamically compare each element with every other element and see which all are having substrings between each other, the solution you gave finds a pre given text within each array element

Comment: thanks, this was the one that was expected, but is anyway of using the already computed value for the future checks, by storing them would help in improving the running time?

Comment: @ShyamSundarR — What do you mean by _"already computed value"_ ?

Comment: i mean if i have an array of length 100, I find first few sub/super strings, can I use them further in such a way to reduce all the comparisons dynamically

Comment: @ShyamSundarR — But current element could also be `super/sub` string of previous array elements right ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use 2 nested loops, but the complexity is O(n^2)

```js
function find_substrings(arr) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<arr.length; j++) {
            if (i !== j && (arr[i].indexOf(arr[j]) > -1 || arr[j].indexOf(arr[i]) > -1)) {
                res.push(arr[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
var arr = ["abc", "abcd", "abcde", "xyz"];
console.log(find_substrings(arr));
```

Comment: You can look at the editted answer above xD. Actually it would work the same as my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use some optimized loops with short cut and an object for the items.

```js
var data = ["abc", "abcd", "42", "abcde", "422", "xyz", "q", "1q"],
    result = function (array) {
        var i, j,
            r = {};

        for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (r[array[i]]) {
                continue;
            }
            for (j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (r[array[j]]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (array[i].indexOf(array[j]) !== -1 || array[j].indexOf(array[i]) !== -1) {
                    r[array[i]] = true;
                    r[array[j]] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return array.filter(function (a) { return r[a]; });
    }(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```